# Length of lists from table and excel are different in Robot framework

Tags: excel, list, robotframework

I'm comparing and matching two lists;
first list/data is collected from excel (${EXCEL DATA} values added to  ${LIST EXCEL})
and the second data/list is collected from a table using xpath and values added to ${TABLE LIST}.
In this example I'm using only one row for the lists. In reality, i want to use 12 values from the excel and therefore want to get 12 values from the table as well. But these 12 values are in different order in the table.
Simplified code:

```
    ${EXCEL LIST}=          Create List
    Open Excel Document     ${EXCEL DATA}         doc_id=doc1
    FOR     ${I}            IN RANGE    2        3
    ${ROWS FROM EXCEL} =    Read Excel Row     ${I}       sheet_name=Sheet1
    Append to list          ${EXCEL LIST}         ${ROWS FROM EXCEL}
    END
    Log to console          ${EXCEL LIST} 

    ${TABLE LIST}=          Create List
    FOR     ${J}            IN RANGE    2       3
    ${FIRST VALUE} =        Get Text     //table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[1]
    Append To List          ${TABLE LIST}        ${FIRST VALUE}
    ${SECOND VALUE} =       Get Text     //table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3]
    Append To List          ${TABLE LIST}        ${SECOND VALUE}
    ${THIRD VALUE} =        Get Text     //table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[5]
    Append To List          ${TABLE LIST}        ${THIRD VALUE}
    END
    #etc
    Log to console      ${TABLE LIST}
    Lists should be equal       ${EXCEL LIST}       ${TABLE LIST}
```

it shows that
Lengths are different: 1 != 12

${EXCEL LIST} length is 1 and ${TABLE LIST} length is 12, while I want to have lists as 1=1.

Is there a simplified method to have lists from the table as length 1?
"Get text" which is causing this? Tried different methods but could not over come this.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Read Excel Row` is appending a list to your created list so it looks like you're returning 1 as the list is nested. Single value result from each table data on the other hand is simply appended straight to the list you created.

You could try appending the table results to a list within the loop and then append that list to your `${TABLE LIST}`

```
${EXCEL LIST}  Create List

Open Excel Document  ${EXCEL DATA}  doc_id=doc1
FOR  ${I}  IN RANGE  2  3
    ${ROWS FROM EXCEL}  Read Excel Row  ${I}  sheet_name=Sheet1
    Append to list  ${EXCEL LIST}  ${ROWS FROM EXCEL}
END

${TABLE LIST}  Create List
FOR  ${J}  IN RANGE  2  3
    ${CURRENT_TABLE}  Create List 
    ${FIRST VALUE}  Get Text  //table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[1]
    Append To List  ${CURRENT_TABLE}  ${FIRST VALUE}
    ${SECOND VALUE}  Get Text  //table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[3]
    Append To List  ${CURRENT_TABLE}  ${SECOND VALUE}
    ${THIRD VALUE}  Get Text  //table[@class="table"]/tbody/tr/td[5]
    Append To List  ${CURRENT_TABLE}  ${THIRD VALUE}
    Append To List  ${TABLE LIST}  ${CURRENT_TABLE}
END
#etc
Log To Console   ${EMPTY}
Log To console   Table List: ${TABLE LIST}
Log To console   Excel List: ${EXCEL LIST}
Lists Should Be Equal  ${EXCEL LIST}  ${TABLE LIST}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: @loffe happy it helps :)